# sed find replace - escape special characters

Tags: sed

I was replacing  one line as at httpd.conf , facing problem withescaping backslash when am using sed ,

source line

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" \"%{True-Client-IP}i\"" combined
```

replaced with

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t %D \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" \"%{True-Client-IP}i\"" combined
```

any tip to escape all these special  characters

Comment: did you want to add `%D` after `%t`?

Comment: yes, using sed or other insert  way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
sed -e 's/%t \\"/%t %D \\"/'
```

Comment: sed -e -i 's/%t \\"/%t %D \\"/'  httpd.conf 
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `-'

Comment: @Christopher without `-i` how would be the changes saved?

Comment: Redirect the result to another file and then replace the old file with the new one.

`sed -e 's/%t \\"/%t %D \\"/' httpd.conf > httpd.conf.new; mv httpd.conf.new httpd.conf`

Answer (score 0):

Through sed,

```
$ sed -i 's/^\(.*%t\)\(.*\)$/\1 %D\2/g' file
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t %D \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" \"%{True-Client-IP}i\"" combined
```

OR

```
$ sed -i 's/%t/%t %D/' file
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t %D \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" \"%{True-Client-IP}i\"" combined
```

Comment: when ever i execute sed command its show up the whole http.conf and nothing changed

Comment: you need to add the inline edit option to make the changes permanent. Updated, my answer.